# How to install Erlang or Elixir with Observer using the Nix package manager?

Tags: erlang, elixir, nix

Every time I install Erlang, I end up without Observer. Used the commands below on a **Ubuntu laptop with Xmonad** and a **Debian 9 running in the cloud**, and seemingly they both resulted in the same package being installed:

- `nix-env -iA pkgs.beam.packages.erlangR22`
- `nix-env -iA nixpkgs.beam.interpreters.erlang`
- `nix-env -iA nixpkgs.beam.interpreters.erlangR22_odbc_javac`

The [Nixpkgs manuals 15.2. BEAM Languages (Erlang, Elixir & LFE) section](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#sec-beam) (Version 19.09.1484.84586a4514d) does not mention Observer at all. It has a fairly recent update by `DianaOlympos` that does mention it, albeit I tried all these packages, but no joy:

> Many Erlang/OTP distributions available in `beam.interpreters` have versions with ODBC and/or Java enabled or without wx (no observer support). For example, there's `beam.interpreters.erlangR22_odbc_javac`, which corresponds to `beam.interpreters.erlangR22` and `beam.interpreters.erlangR22_nox`, which corresponds to `beam.interpreters.erlangR22`.

[Shane Sveller pointed it out that the `wxGTK` package needs to be set up](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/how-to-install-erlang-with-observer/5028/2) using `propagatedBuildInputs`, but not sure how to do that. (Simply just installing `wxGTK` then Erlang doesn't work of course; was naive enough to try it. Also found out that [chapter 20 of Nix Pills](https://nixos.org/nixos/nix-pills/basic-dependencies-and-hooks.html) is exactly about this topic.)

This is also kind of a follow-up to the question "[How to install Erlang/Elixir on a non-NixOS system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51371028)", but I didn't realize it then that Observer is missing...

---

update: Apparently, [it works somewhere out of the box](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/how-to-install-erlang-with-observer/5028/5). (Probably on NixOS.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have an overwrite for erlang, such that wx support is enabled:

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:

with pkgs;

let
  inherit (lib) optionals;

  erlang_wx = erlangR21.override {
    wxSupport = true;
  };

  elixir = (beam.packagesWith erlang_wx).elixir.override {
    version = "1.9.2";
    rev = "ffe7a577cc80f37381dc289c820842d346002364";
    sha256 = "19yn6nx6r627f5zbyc7ckgr96d6b45sgwx95n2gp2imqwqvpj8wc";
  };
in

mkShell {
  buildInputs = [ elixir git ]

    # For file_system on Linux.
    ++ optionals stdenv.isLinux [ inotify-tools wxGTK ]

    # For file_system on macOS.
    ++ optionals stdenv.isDarwin (with darwin.apple_sdk.frameworks; [
      # For file_system on macOS.
      CoreFoundation
      CoreServices
      wxmac
    ]);
}
```

Save this (as [`shell.nix`](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sec-nix-shell) for example), and just run it:

```
$ nix-shell shell.nix

# or, if you are in the same directory:
$ nix-shell
```

Works on my machine!

---

Note: `wxmac` in `buildInputs` is specific to MacOS (and `wxGTK` to Linux). To find the right package for your OS, [here are the available `wx` packages](https://nixos.org/nixos/packages.html?channel=nixos-19.09&query=%5Ewx).

Comment: Thanks! In the end, the solution is way more mundane, but accepted your answer because it is very educational on how to write a `nix-shell` script.

Comment: Edited your answer to make the `wx` packages part of the `optionals` too, but was only able to try out the Linux-side of things. If you don't agree with any of the changes, just nix mine. Thanks again! (For reference to future self: see sections _5.1.5.17. lib.lists.optional_ and _5.1.5.18. lib.lists.optionals_ in the [Nixpkgs Manual](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/)).

Answer (score 1):

Kind of ashamed to admit that I am an idiot, but Observer was there all this time ([along with `net_adm`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59219351/what-could-cause-the-net-adm-kernel-erlang-module-to-be-unavailable))...

For some reason, it wouldn't autocomplete on the `erl` shell, but once `observer:start().` was typed in and executed, it would recognize the module, and provide a list of available functions when hitting the Tab key.

I probably messed up translating between `iex` and `erl` ( `observer.start().` and other combinations), and I assumed that the resulting error message (together with no autocompletion) means that the module was missing.